# How to change the package path inside an archive created by `python setup.py bdist`?

Tags: python, path, packaging, setup.py, distutils

I am creating a `.zip` package by command `python setup.py bdist`.
After the archive is created, the main folder which I packaged is placed at path `<archive_name>.zip/<Python_path>/Lib/site-packages/<packaged_folder>`.

What I want to achieve is the folder path inside archive to keep some specific, as when I run `python setup.py bdist` statement for the same code on different environments, the path inside archive gets changed based on Python version and platform.

Edit: I am not talking about `--dist-dir` option.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to explicitly call the `install` and `bdist_dumb` commands with some options:
<sup>(yes, this is a [real command](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/builtdist.html))</sup>

```
setup.py install --root=build\bdist --install-lib=. bdist_dumb --bdist-dir=build\bdist
```

For the `install` command you need to override the following options:

```
--install-lib                        installation directory for all module distributions
--install-headers                    installation directory for C/C++ headers
--install-scripts                    installation directory for Python scripts
--install-data                       installation directory for data files
```

---

Note that the `bdist` command is obsolete and what you want is basically what [wheel format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#canonical-specification) is for:

> A wheel is a ZIP-format archive with a specially formatted file name and the `.whl` extension. It contains a single distribution nearly as it would be installed according to [PEP 376](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376) with a particular installation scheme. Although a specialized installer is recommended, a wheel file may be installed by simply unpacking into site-packages with the standard `unzip` tool while preserving enough information to spread its contents out onto their final paths at any later time.

See the following links for an up-to-date information on packaging Python projects:

- [Tutorial: Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) (more recent);
- [Guide: Packaging and distributing projects](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/).